# Javascript - How to add <input> element into div using createElement Method

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with simple thing.
I want to add a  element into html div tag using createElement Method. I have tried a lot of diferent ways but always getting the same result - nothing happens.

This is my code:

```js
function changeReleaseDate() 
{
    var parentElement = document.getElementByClassName("container body-content");
 var existingElement = document.getElementByClassName("btn btn-default");
 var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "text";
    newInput.className = "form-control";
 parentElement.insertBefore(newInput, existingElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
     <h2>Index</h2>
  <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="changeReleaseDate()" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
  <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy;My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to use appendChild but in this case input field was placed out of div.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getElementByClassName` should be [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

This method returns a `HTMLCollection`, so to access the first element from this list you need to use bracket with index `0`:

```
var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("container body-content")[0];
var existingElement = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default")[0];
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jak4efau/

However it's more convenient in your case to use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method:

```
var parentElement = document.querySelector(".container body-content");
var existingElement = document.querySelector(".btn.btn-default");
```

Also note, that you need to take care of the case when user clicks button multiple times, you probably don't want to append multiple input fields.

Comment: Specifically, `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList`.